# Unable to start locastack from console

Tags: python, ubuntu, localstack

I have localstack installed on my vm when I try to run, its throwing me following error.

```sh
guest@VirtualBox:~$ localstack start
```

Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.

```
ERROR: 'cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/localstack/infra && cp /tmp/localstack.es.zip es.zip && unzip -q es.zip && mv elasticsearch* elasticsearch && rm es.zip': [es.zip] 

End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of es.zip or
        es.zip.zip, and cannot find es.zip.ZIP, period.

Error starting infrastructure: Command 'cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/localstack/infra && cp /tmp/localstack.es.zip es.zip && unzip -q es.zip && mv elasticsearch* elasticsearch && rm es.zip' returned non-zero exit status 9

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/localstack", line 86, in <module>
    infra.start_infra()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/localstack/services/infra.py", line 366, in start_infra
    raise e
subprocess32.CalledProcessError: Command 'cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/localstack/infra && cp /tmp/localstack.es.zip es.zip && unzip -q es.zip && mv elasticsearch* elasticsearch && rm es.zip' returned non-zero exit status 9
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What would you expect and why should happen what you expect?

Comment: That seems like a bug in the installation, can you please raise a ticket here: https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Answer (score 0):

@Shital This should be fixed in the latest version. Can you try running:

```
rm -f /tmp/localstack.es.zip
pip install --no-cache --upgrade localstack
localstack start
```

Related issue has been fixed here: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/213